# Pokemon Let's Go Awakening Value (AV) for all who level, or just the battle winner?

Tags: pokemon-lets-go

In Pokemon Let's Go, I only see Awakening Value (AV) bonuses for the pokemon who leveled by winning the battle. Do pokemon who level without battling (e.g. through capturing pokemon or by shared exp) still get AV bonuses?

Answer (score 6):

**All Pokemon who level up gain AV values**

As stated by Bulbapedia

> At each level-up, a Pokémon will gain one AV on a random stat.

[Awakening values](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Awakening_values)

And Serebii

> While each level you will get a random AV with each level up...

[Pokémon Stats](https://www.serebii.net/letsgopikachueevee/stats.shtml)

Each Level up will give your Pokemon 1 random AV on any stat, it's just that the game will only show the stats growth from the Pokemon that is in battle, all other team members stats change are not shown like in previous games.